# Browsing Ruby code a la Smalltalk?

Tags: ruby

What's the closest equivalent of the Smalltalk Class Hierarchy Browser?
I've seen some workarounds like [this](http://www.lovettsoftware.com/blogengine.net/post/2012/01/27/Ruby-Class-Hierarchy-to-DGML.aspx), but it seems not scriptable.

[image: Smalltalk Class Hierarchy Browser]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really isn't one, at least not with a Smalltalk-like UI including static and dynamic behaviors.

Eclipse and IntelliJ both have some structural insight. Eclipse has a view sort-of similar to a browser. The biggest issue with either is that unless you're working on live objects (e.g., debugging) you won't necessarily know all of an object's behavior since some is defined at runtime. A static view without an image or partial runtime cannot give a complete picture.

IntelliJ does a decent job of figuring things out. For example, a class with an `attr_accessor :foo` will show the `@foo` instance variable in the structure pane. I'm not sure you can configure the UI around to be more browser-like, though; Eclipse is better in this regard–each "level" can be added separately.

<sup>*(Since 1994-95ish I've felt we kept taking steps backwards, it's only recently that IDEs have gotten smart enough to give me back some of the productivity I had with Smalltalk/Lisp. Smalltalk's image-based runtime confers a lot of advantages in this regard.)*</sup>

Answer (score 2):

For more fun, you could take a [Moose](http://www.moosetechnology.org) image, write a Ruby parser with PetitParser and a Glamour code browser. That would provide a Smalltalk UI :)

[edit] Oh, someone didn't like the answer. Care to explain why? It is a perfectly good solution.