# Does an (experimental) class browser exist for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ide, smalltalk, pry, maglev

Does an (experimental) class browser exist for Ruby?

I am talking about a class browser/editor combination similar to that of most Smalltalk implementations (i.e. focused on [runtime] classes/objects instead of .rb files)

[image: Squeak Smalltalk Class Browser]

P.S.: it looks like pry is already able to do a lot of the things that would be needed by a smalltalk style class browser? https://speakerdeck.com/u/rahult/p/pry-an-irb-alternative-on-steroids

P.S.2: Looks like the Seaside Smalltalk framework has a [web browser based class browser](http://www.seaside.st/files/e5/j0odnetjvprbsy8kyp45g0q7blphkn/browser.png)

P.S.3: MagLev/Webtools is the closest I have found yet:

[image]

P.S.4: Apparently http://tibleiz.net/code-browser/index.html has Ruby support and is able to present a Smalltalk like class browser:

[image]

Comment: It could be done from a pure metaprograming perspective if you combined it with ri or RDoc. But I don't think anyones actually gone to the work to make a Tk GUI for it or anything.

Comment: ri/RDoc is statically generated, I am talking about live objects like in pry/irb. A Tk GUI would be backwards, Qt might be better in this case (or perhaps web-based, served from a local ruby http daemon)

Comment: texasbruce> that was my understanding of it, or is ri/RDoc able to generate data from runtime?

Comment: What is the difference between running RDoc runtime and running it on the files that have the relevant definitions?

Comment: That's not what I mean. What I ment was you use standard Ruby meta-programing and then use ri to get the human written documentation for the class in question.

Comment: @linuxios `ri` requires that documentation is pre-generated. Pry, by contrast, is able to extract documentation at runtime without requiring it to be pregenerated. In fact if you change the source/docs for a method at runtime, pry is able to show the new source/docs.

Comment: @banister: I know. The point is, of you use that to get the human part of the documentation, but extract the other pars at runtimeq, I think you'd have what's wanted.

Comment: @Linuxios I don't understand. Pry can extract exactly the same documentation that `ri` would generate -- the comments above the method. How is `ri` even required here?

Comment: @banister: Nevermind. You're right

Comment: Also have a look here: [Stackoverflow: Browsing Ruby code a la Smalltalk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894374/browsing-ruby-code-a-la-smalltalk)

Answer (score 7):

Check out the [maglev/webtools project on github](https://github.com/maglev/webtools/tree/refactoring), as well as the [rubymirrors gem](https://github.com/timfel/rubymirrors). It already provides a class browser and workspace for multiple Ruby implementations, and a graphical debugger works on MagLev as well (not so much on MRI).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to build one, the easiest would be to use [MOOSE](http://www.moosetechnology.org) and build the browser with Glamour, on top of a Ruby parser written in PetitParser. Then you could use Pharo as your Ruby IDE.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the **Maglev Database Explorer** [1, 2] as well.

[1] Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27mS1BNP7wQ

[2] Gem: https://github.com/matthias-springer/maglev-database-explorer-gem

Answer (score 1):

There is. It is called Reflexive. https://github.com/dolzenko/reflexive

(I've never taken the time to try it though, so I am curious about other experiences with it.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is what it looks like on my machine while browsing a Sinatra module: http://i.imgur.com/01OMy.png The techniques it uses might be interesting, but it does not look nor behave like a Smalltalk style class browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with it (and it is old), but may be [rbbr](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?rbbr) still works.